# How to hide specific HTML paragraph element

Tags: html, css

I would like to hide `<p>class="color-grey-9" Rate</p>` element.

```
<div> class="detail-desc"

    <p>class="color-grey-9" Category</p>
    <p>class="color-grey-9" Rate</p>
    <p>class="color-grey-9" Country</p>

</div>
```

Comment: with CSS  `display:none;`

Comment: Seriously, if someone posted a question like this to you, what would you say?

Comment: Please review how to define attributes on HTML elements, the code you have isn't valid.

Comment: <div> class="detail-desc"

    <p class="color-grey-9"> Category</p>
    <p class="color-grey-9"> Rate</p>
    <p class="color-grey-9"> Country</p>

</div>

Comment: sorry it was a typing errro

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use CSS 3 selector to apply your style, in this case I used the `:nth-of-type(n)`selector, which matches every element that is the nth child, of a particular type, of its parent. Using `:nth-of-type(n)` you do not need to introduce any additional `hidden` class.

Use `display:none` to hide an element, it will not be available in the page and does not occupy any space.

Use `visibility:hidden` to hide an element, it will still take up the same space as before when visible.

```css
.color-grey-9:nth-of-type(2){
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<div class="detail-desc">
  <p class="color-grey-9">Category</p>
  <p class="color-grey-9">Rate</p>
  <p class="color-grey-9">Country</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, your classes are improperly set, and you can apply the hidden attribute in your CSS file.

```css
.color-grey-9-hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="detail-desc"> 
  <p class="color-grey-9">Category</p>
  <p class="color-grey-9-hidden">Rate</p>
  <p class="color-grey-9">Country</p>
</div>
```